# How to eat HTML tags?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is there any function that converts

```
<a href="test.php"/>
```

to

```
&lt; href=&quot;test.php&quot;/&gt;
```

It would be helpful if all html characters were converted in the similar manner.

Is there a function or library to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var eaten:String = myString.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').
                            replace(/</g,'&lt;').
                            replace(/>/g,'&gt;').
                            replace(/"/g,'&quot;');
```

Comment: I was actually looking for something which does that for all the symbols here: http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/webstuff/htmlsymbols.html

Comment: You don't need to. Those characters aren't parsed (only the above four are) and you should be able to use the direct UTF-8 without escaping them.

Comment: This seems to replace only the first instance of the character.

Comment: Use a regex pattern with the global modifier instead of a string. For example, _replace(/&/g, '&amp;')._

Comment: @Kishi: Why? o_O? Regex is much slower

Comment: @M28 It's not, really, given the circunstances. He needs to replace _all_ the special characters, _String.replace(String, String)_ will replace only the first match.

Comment: Well, I thought that its behaviour was only in javascript.

Comment: True. It seems to replace only the first (which I thought against). Updating the post with a regex...

Answer (score 0):

use HttpUtility

Comment: I need to do this with Actionscript! So, looking for a AS3 library.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like encodeURIComponent may be what you're after:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#encodeURIComponent%28%29

Comment: encodeURIComponent converts <a href="test.php"/> to **%3Ca%20href%3D%22test.php%22%2F%3E**. Oops!